# Heat definition in isotherm and first principle of thermodinamic

Tags: thermodynamics

We know that the heat Q can be computed by $Q=cm\Delta T$ and in a phase change by $Q=Lm$ (L latent heat).
In isotherm process and with no change of phase we can't use those formulas and there's no formula for defintion of Q (correct me if I'm wrong). Usually we use $\Delta U=Q-L$ but so we are defining Q by the first principle and so in isotherm process the first principle is more a definiton that a principle.
Is this observation correct?

Answer (score 1):

> In isotherm process and with no change of phase we can't use those
>   formulas and there's no formula for defintion of Q (correct me if I'm
>   wrong).

You are correct that you can't use those two formulas for an isothermal process with no phase change, but you can determine $Q$ from the first law.

> Usually we use $\Delta U=Q-L$ but so we are defining Q by the first
>   principle so in isotherm process the first principle is more a
>   definiton that a principle. Is this observation correct?

The first law for a closed system is not your equation which uses latent heat, but the following:

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

Where $Q$ is heat and is positive if added to the system, and $W$ is work and is positive if done by the system. The first law is  not a definition of heat, but relates heat and work to changes in internal energy.

For an ideal gas undergoing an isothermal process ($\Delta T=0$, and $Pv=$ constant),$\Delta U=0$ because $\Delta U=mC_{v}\Delta T$ for any process. Therefore, for an ideal gas $Q=W$, which is to say that the heat added (or removed) from the system exactly equals the work done by (or on) the system. For an ideal gas that work would be:

$$W=RTln\frac{v_2}{v_1}=RTln\frac{P_1}{P_2}$$

Where 2 and 1 denote final and initial values, respectively, of pressure and volume.

> And if I have no choice I think that in this case the first law is a
>   definition of heat. Suppose a beginner student, without knowing the
>   first law, ask to you how the heat is defined in a rigorous way in
>   that 'case of no choice' what definition you give to him if you can't
>   use first law?

I would first give the student the overarching general thermodynamics definition of heat:

HEAT: Energy transfer between a system and its surroundings due solely to a temperature difference between them.

I would then point out that the emphasis in thermodynamics is the effect of heat transfer on the properties of substances (temperature, internal kinetic and/or potential energy, phase changes, etc.) and the applicable equations as we have been talking about in this post.

But I would also point out that although in thermodynamics we often don't need to worry about the exact *mechanism* of the heat transfer (conduction, convection, radiation) one or more of those mechanisms has to be involved, and there are well defined laws and equations for each mechanism. For example we have (1) Fourier's Law of Conduction (for conduction), (2) Newton's Law of Cooling (for convection), and (3) Stephan-Boltzmann law of thermal radiation (for radiation), and the associated equations for each.

In our example of the isothermal process for an ideal gas we didn't need to know about the heat transfer mechanism involved. It was sufficient to know the heat transfer equals the work. But if we wanted to know the laws governing the heat transfer mechanism, there are such laws and associate equations, depending on which mechanism(s) is (are) involved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My question concerning the logical setting of first law. If one ask to compute Q in isotherm without first law you can't, so I think that in this case the law is not a principle but a definition of Q. A law is a relation of quantity that we have before defined. If we give the first law in isotherm wihtout before defining Q in fact we are defining Q by the first law. I'm wrong?

Comment: @asv Not saying you're wrong, I just don't see it that way. I don't think the first law "defines" heat. Nor do I think $mc\Delta T$ nor $mL$ defines heat. Heat is defined as energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. How much heat is involved is determined by the effect of the transfer on the system, be it these equations or the first law.

Comment: You say "Heat is defined as energy transfer due solely to temperature difference." but in isotherm there's not difference of temperature. Work has an exact definiton by line integral of force over a path. What is the exact definition of heat? Is there a rigorius mathematical definiton valid for any trasfomation?

Comment: @asv in an isothermal process the temperature difference is between the system undergoing the process and the surroundings that supplies heat to (or removes heat from) the system. “Isothermal” means the system temperature doesn’t change during the transfer. The reason is, in the expansion of an ideal gas example, the gas simultaneously uses that energy to do work on the surroundings. For an isothermal phase change the system uses the heat transferred from the surroundings to cause the phase change.

Comment: Ok so, suppose we don't know the first law, if we would compute the heat of the system we must compute the heat supplied from surrounding by the traditional formulas $Q=cm \Delta T$ or $Q=Lm$ applied to the surroundings in this case. I'm right?

Comment: @asv Yes you could do that if you knew the properties of the surroundings. But you couldn't use the first equation if the surroundings was a thermal reservoir who's temperature doesn't change. You could use the second  equation if you knew L and m of the surroundings. But if the surroundings was a thermal reservoir and does not undergo a phase change when transferring heat, then you have no choice but the first law.

Comment: And if I have no choice I think that in this case the first law is a definiton of heat. Suppose a beginner student, without knowing the first law, ask to you how the heat is defined in a rigorous way in that 'case of no choice' what definiton you give to him if you can't use first law? I want a rigorous definition in all cases before first law. A law can't relate physical quantities if these physical quantities weren't rigorous defined in all cases before the law itself. I can't say $F=ma$ if I don't define what $a$ is in all cases and we know $a= \Delta v/ \Delta t$.

Comment: @asv I think I know what your difficulty is. There are laws associated with the effect of heat transfer on systems properties and those are sufficient most of the time in thermodynamics. But there are also well defined  laws on the mechanisms of heat transfer. I have revised my answer to address that. Hope that helps.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you take this: http://web.ist.utl.pt/berberan/data/68.pdf at beginning of page 9 of pdf file, we read: "dU − dW = dQ, (13) where Q is called heat." It seems that in axiomatic thermodymics Q is defined by first-law.

Comment: @asv I read your reference. You are certainly free to interpret it to mean the first law is an axiomatic definition of heat. However I didn't see it as reaching such a conclusion. As I read the article, the focus was on showing that neither heat nor work is a state function, as internal energy,  because they depend on the process between states an therefore they should not be given as exact differentials $dq$ and $dw$ but rather as partial differentials $δq$ and $δw$.

Comment: Ok, thank you for yout comment.